# testhost.deps.json file is not found while running nunit test in azure agent

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I'm running a few API tests on azure devops agent and getting this warning error message

```
  2021-05-21T13:42:29.0650201Z ##[error]DiscoveryMessage : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process exited with error: Cannot use file stream for [C:\a\r1\a\_Automation-Build\drop\TestAutomation.UI.PageObject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\testhost.deps.json]: No such file or directory
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0661479Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]DiscoveryMessage : Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process exited with error: Cannot use file stream for [C:\a\r1\a\_Automation-Build\drop\TestAutomation.UI.PageObject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\testhost.deps.json]: No such file or directory
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0663114Z A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0663661Z Failed to run as a self-contained app.
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0664305Z   - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\a\r1\a\_Automation-Build\drop\TestAutomation.UI.PageObject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\testhost.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0665393Z   - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\a\r1\a\_Automation-Build\drop\TestAutomation.UI.PageObject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\testhost.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0666319Z . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0667169Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.ThrowOnTestHostExited(Boolean testHostExited)
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0668081Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
2021-05-21T13:42:29.0668810Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
```

I've also went through that article https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/microsoft/vstest/2218/540508574 and i'm not sure how i can apply test files selection with `test plan` option instead `test assemblies`[image] [image]

Answer (score 6):

> A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.

Based on the error message, you could refer to this [Github ticket](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569).

Here are the methods you could try:

1. Change the Test files path in VSTest task(From `**\*test*.dll` to `**\*test.dll`).
2. Remove references from one test assembly to another
3. Update Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK to 16.6.1

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, I've seen that possible solution before but none of all three options didn't work for me 1. In my visual studio test task I'm running the tests as a test plan but not as test assemblies 3. i've downgraded  Microsoft.NET.Test.SDK to 16.2.0 but that also didn't help

Comment: @DenisS. What kind of agent are you using? Microsoft-hosted or self-hosted.  When you run the test on your local machine, can you see the same error?

Comment: It's working fine once i ran the test locally. No errors shows up. The error occurs once i ran the tests on azure agent machine. I'm using Microsoft-hosted  agent.

Comment: Can you try to modify the test files (`**\*test.dll`) in test assemblies  mode and run the test with test plan mode? You could check if it has the same issue.

Comment: That's the thing that i'm running tests as a test plan and there is no field to modify the test files (**\\*test.dll) like in test assemblies mode

Comment: You could try to modify the test files in test assemblies mode and go back to test plan mode when run the test. The settings will be inherited.

Comment: Oh, really?! let me try that

Comment: Unfortunately still same error occurs. The (**\\*test.dll) for test assemblies was applied though

Comment: @DenisS. any success with resolving this issue? I am getting exactly the same behavior on Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens because the test runner picks up its own related files, plus potentially other dlls you don't need to test, and it cannot test them properly.

You can usually see which files it is trying to test in the build output, something like this:

```
[command]C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe 
"@D:\a\_temp\picufy3glth.tmp"
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.3.0-preview-20220626-01 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
vstest.console.exe "D:\a\1\s\Proj\bin\Release\net6.0\MyTestProject.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\Proj\bin\Release\net6.0\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\Proj\bin\Release\net6.0\es\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources.dll"
```

We had this issue on a basic .NET v6 test project (but contained in a solution multi-targeting other framework versions).

We solved it by adding exclusions for all "testhost" files and "Microsoft" dlls to the testfiles listing:

```
!**\testhost*.*
!**\Microsoft*.dll
```

Comment: This was my problem as well.  Interesting to note that this project is dotnet 3.1, but also multi targeting (4.7.2).  Perhaps that has something to do with it?  But your solution worked for me.